# How to redistribute points evenly over a curve

Tags: python, math, 3d

I have some arbitrary curve in 3 dimensions made up of a list of XYZ cartesian points.  The points are not evenly distributed (theres a time factor).  How can I 'rebuild' the curve with a given number of points that should make up the curve.  I see this done in 3D modeling programs so im pretty sure its possible, I just dont know how.

[image]

Based on the answer, i needed it in python so i started working to convert interparc into python.  I got as far as the linear interpolation.  It is probably inefficient and has redundancies, but maybe it will be useful to someone http://pastebin.com/L9NFvJyA

Comment: So, you've already calculated the best-fit curve and now you just want to show it using points? Or you still need to do so? Or neither?

Comment: No i have points that define a curve, and i need to evenly distribute the points along this curve.  The 'curve' is not calculated though, its just a dataset of points

Comment: If you have points that 'define' a curve, you should be able to calculate the curve. I'm not quite sure what you mean "be redistributed" otherwise.

Comment: I added a picture to show what I am talking about.  The points are not evenly spaced along the curve

Comment: The picture shows me why you think you should be able to do this without calculating anything. But more points really doesn't make a difference! How do you know, with absolute certainty, the value in between any two points, even if they are separated by only a tiny epsilon? You still need to either use some kind of regression, or just take the average of the two neighboring points to find more values that you can choose to either use or not to. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Nonlinear_regression

Comment: Your question is tagged [python]. Do you need a solution to be in Python, or will the Matlab code below suit your needs ?

Comment: I would like it in python but i could convert matlab code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use [interparc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34874-interparc), a tool of mine designed to do exactly that. It fits a spline through a general space curve in 2 or more dimensions, then chooses points that are equally spaced in terms of distance along that curve. In the case of a cubic spline, the solution uses an odesolver to do what must be a numerical integration so it is a bit slower, but it is still reasonably fast. In many cases, a simple linear interpolation (as I used here) will be entirely adequate, and extremely fast.

The curve may be completely general, even crossing over itself. I'll give a simple example for a 3-d space curve:

```
t = linspace(0,1,500).^3;
x = sin(2*pi*t);
y = sin(pi*t);
z = cos(3*x + y);
plot3(x,y,z,'o')
grid on
box on
view(-9,12)
```

[image]

```
xyzi = interparc(100,x,y,z,'lin');
plot3(xyzi(:,1),xyzi(:,2),xyzi(:,3),'o')
box on
grid on
view(-9,12)
```

[image]

Comment: wow this looks really promising, the curve doesnt need to close does it?

Comment: The curve can be completely general, with no need to be closed. I've provided that capability though, in case the first and last points are the same.

Comment: Do you have the algorithm written down?  I dont use matlab and it is pretty hard to parse through what is happening

Answer (score 8):

First of all, thank you to Mr. John D'Errico for interparc. What a great job!

I too was facing this problem but am not familiar with the MATLAB engine API. Given that, I tried to convert part of the interparc Matlab code to Python (just including the linear interpolant because it would be enough to address my problem).

And so here is my code; hope it can help all the pythonics seeking something similar:

```
import numpy as np

def interpcurve(N,pX,pY):
#equally spaced in arclength
N=np.transpose(np.linspace(0,1,N))

#how many points will be uniformly interpolated?
nt=N.size

#number of points on the curve
n=pX.size
pxy=np.array((pX,pY)).T
p1=pxy[0,:]
pend=pxy[-1,:]
last_segment= np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(p1,pend))
epsilon= 10*np.finfo(float).eps

#IF the two end points are not close enough lets close the curve
if last_segment > epsilon*np.linalg.norm(np.amax(abs(pxy),axis=0)):
    pxy=np.vstack((pxy,p1))
    nt = nt + 1
else:
    print('Contour already closed')

pt=np.zeros((nt,2))

#Compute the chordal arclength of each segment.
chordlen = (np.sum(np.diff(pxy,axis=0)**2,axis=1))**(1/2)
#Normalize the arclengths to a unit total
chordlen = chordlen/np.sum(chordlen)
#cumulative arclength
cumarc = np.append(0,np.cumsum(chordlen))

tbins= np.digitize(N,cumarc) # bin index in which each N is in

#catch any problems at the ends
tbins[np.where(tbins<=0 | (N<=0))]=1
tbins[np.where(tbins >= n | (N >= 1))] = n - 1      

s = np.divide((N - cumarc[tbins]),chordlen[tbins-1])
pt = pxy[tbins,:] + np.multiply((pxy[tbins,:] - pxy[tbins-1,:]),(np.vstack([s]*2)).T)

return pt
```

Comment: i will upload soon, but i worked on this with some students and came up with the full code as well.  but yes, this is useful to many people i think

Comment: I had to change your "|" operator in the two "tbins[np.where...]" lines to np.bitwise_or; otherwise they don't function the way you intended (I think). I also commented out the curve-closing block as it was creating odd behavior for my non-closed-curve application. Otherwise, nice job. I hope that someone pythonizes the full interparc code as it is incredibly useful.

Comment: In addition to previous comment, I had to change following lines like this after getting rid of curve-closing block:
s = np.divide((N - cumarc[tbins-1]),chordlen[tbins-1])
pt = pxy[tbins-1,:] + np.multiply((pxy[tbins,:] - pxy[tbins-1,:]),(np.vstack([s]*ndim)).T). Now, this gives the same result as original Matlab function for linear interpolation.

Comment: This worked super well for me, but required that I normalize the inputs to be of equal magnitude before running interpcurve. Just a heads up for future users.

Answer (score 2):

Your "curve" is a bunch of line-segments that connect a bunch of points.  Each line-segment has a length; the total length of your curve is the sum of these line-segments' lengths.

So calculate `d = totalCurveLength / (numberOfPoints - 1)`, and split the curve into `(numberOfPoints - 1)` chunks of length `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following, but instead of storing the actual data, maybe store the delta from point to point, then rebuild the curve from the deltas, so there wouldn't be any empty spots?  This would, however, change the shape of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup, `interparc` assumes your points are listed in path order (i.e. the points go from start to end tracing the curve). If using real world data, this may not be the case.

If you happen to know the connectivity of your points (i.e. which points connect to form a chord), you can use `libigl` to sort the points in path order:

```py
import igl

path, _, _ = igl.edges_to_path(edges)  # edges = N x 2 array of point indices

points = points[path]

# Now use `interparc`...
```

If you don't know the connectivity, you could try using [`pykdtree`](https://github.com/storpipfugl/pykdtree):

- Create an empty `N X 2` array called `edges`
- Pick a random point in the `points` dataset (say index `5` of `points`)
- Use a `KDTree` to find the indices of the two nearest neighbors in the data
- Store the pairs of indices in `edges`
  (i.e. if `points[5]` is connected to `points[10]` and `points[3]`, you'd do something like:

```py
edges = np.append(edges, [[5, 10], [5, 3]], axis=0)
```

- Pop points `5`, `10`, and `3` from `points` and continue continue the algorithm at points `10` and `3` until there are no more points left.

The above is just an idea.