# Calculate evenly distributed points along a curve

Tags: javascript, geometry, bezier, curve

I'm using this equation to calculate a series of points along a quadratic curve:

```
// Returns a point on a quadratic bezier curve with Robert Penner's optimization of the standard equation
result.x = sx + t * (2 * (1 - t) * (cx - sx) + t * (ex - sx));
result.y = sy + t * (2 * (1 - t) * (cy - sy) + t * (ey - sy));
```

Sadly the points are unevenly distributed, as you can see in the dashed-line rendering below. The points are denser in the middle of the curve, and are further spaced apart near the edges. How can I calculate a evenly distributed set of points along a quadratic bezier curve?

Please note that I'm using this for rendering a dashed line, so a slow solution in MATLAB or something will not do. I need a fast solution that will fit inside a renderer. This is not for research or a one-off calculation!

[image: dashed]

**Edit:** I'm not asking how to accomplish the above. The above is MY RENDERING! I already know how to estimate the length of a bezier, calculate the number of points, etc, etc. What I need is a **better bezier point interpolation algorithm** since the one I have calculates points unevenly distributed along the curve!

Comment: Similar to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244305/how-to-redistribute-points-evenly-over-a-curve) but I want something much simpler and code in JS.

Comment: https://github.com/MadLittleMods/svg-curve-lib  , 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/moving-ships-between-two-planets-along-a-bezier-missing-some-equations-for-acce/5427#5427 ....when looking for an answer for this look up even speed movement along a path, or something like that, thats how I usually find the answer

Answer (score 4):

You want to generate equidistant (by arc length) subdivision of quadratic Bezier curves.

So you need subdivision procedure and [function for calculation of curve length](https://gist.github.com/tunght13488/6744e77c242cc7a94859).

Find length of the whole curve (`L`), estimate desired number of segments (`N`), then generate subdivision points, adjusting `t` parameters to get Bezier segments with length about `L/N`

Example: you find L=100 and want N=4 segments. Get t=1/2, subdivide curve by two parts and get length of the first part. If length > 50, diminish t and subdivide curve again. Repeat (use binary search) until length value becomes near 50. Remember t value and do the same procedure to get segments with length=25 for the first and for the second halves of the curve.

Comment: I'm already doing that! What I need is a better bezier point interpolation algorithm since the one I'm doing causes the points to be unevenly distributed!!

Comment: Look at the equation I've provided in the first para of my post. I need a better version of that. An equation where you provide the T value and it provides the x/y of the bezier point evenly distributed along the curve, where T=0 is the start point and T=1 is the end point.

Comment: I did describe such process in short - but you need to search t values for equidistant point with numeric methods

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses the THREE.js library, which is not in the OP's question, but may be useful if only to look at how they approach it:

```
  var curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve(
    new THREE.Vector2( -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 20, 15 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 10, 0 )
);

  var points = curve.getSpacedPoints(numPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to explore this question for a project. I think the answer above by "MBo" is mostly right, though computationally expensive

The parameter *t* based approach is easier to compute but would not yield even distances. If the curve has a sharp turn there the points will be more dense (e.g. the curve C in the picture).

Point to be noted that the parameter *t* which runs from 0 to 1, is not the fraction of length covered.
In fact it is expensive to compute a point on curve from a given fraction of length, because there is no closed formula. So it'll be iterative approximation.

However given a *t* value you can split the original curve into two, and calculate their lengths. So the solution is to repeatedly split by *t*, calculate length and adjust *t* until *t* reaches the target fraction *f* of length.

You can write the approximation method and call it for every *f* from 0, 0.01, 0.02 and so on for 100 uniformly spaced points. But I think the runtime would be too high.

This is what I ended up doing in my case. It is an approximate solution, but efficient. Recursively split a curve at t = 0.5, then split left and right halves. Until each segment length is less than say 5 (pixel). When the segments are shorter than 5 pixels, it is fair to assume they are straight line segments.

Now you can interpolate for every fraction of length say *f* (not to confuse with *t*). Because every split point has an *f* value (length upto that point divided by total length). Suppose a query fraction *f* falls between two *f* values *f1* and *f2* of two consecutive split points.

f1 => (x1, y1)   // known

f' => ??

f2 => (x2, y2)   // known

where f1 <= f <= f2

Apply simple linear interpolation to find the coordinate at *f*. It's an O(1) operation. You can write a loop to emit points at a fixed intervals of f values by scanning the split points.

---

P.S. I checked THREE.js source on github. The method curve.getSpacedPoints uses uniform t-values. So it's not really "uniformly" spaced.